# Python: how to catch calls to derived class?

Tags: python

Say I have a base class `base` and a derived class `derive`.

I want to do two things: override one method in `base`. This is done by simply overriding it in `derive`.

However, I **also** want to do something to all the other methods on `base`. What I want to do is simply call the `base` function's method, then multiply the result by `-1`.

As you can see, I am now forced to write out all these methods in `derive`, call the `super().method`, then multiply by `-1` and return.

Is there not a way to catch **all** these other functions in `derive`, then do it for them all simultaneously?

```
class Base:
    def override():
        pass # override this manually in derived
    def method1():
        pass # multiply by -1 in derive
    def method2():
        pass # multiply by -1 in derive
    def method3():
        pass # multiply by -1 in derive
    def method4():
        pass # multiply by -1 in derive

class Derived(Base)

    # now what do I do here that avoids writing out all the methods??
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a small change to the `Base` class, adding a `_multiplier()` method that you override in `Derived`:

```
class Base:
    def _multiplier():
        return 1
    def method1():
        return some_value * self._multiplier()
    def method2():
        return some_value * self._multiplier()
    def method3():
        return some_value * self._multiplier()
    def method4():
        return some_value * self._multiplier()

class Derived(Base):
    def _multiplier():
        return -1
```